# ssh to one particular server does not change gnome-terminal tab title

Tags: ssh, linux

I manage about 15 servers that all run Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit

I use gnome-terminal to ssh into them. When I log in, the gnome-terminal tab title changes to "anachrophile@hostname: ~" on all except one server.

What triggers gnome-terminal to change the tab title when I run ssh? What would be different about that one server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will usually be set either in your own .bashrc or .bash_profile or in the system profiles files. There'll be a part of the file that looks somehting like

```
case $TERM in
    xterm*)
            if [ -e /etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-xterm ]; then
                    PROMPT_COMMAND=/etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-xterm
            else
        PROMPT_COMMAND='printf "\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/~}"'
            fi
            ;;
    screen)
            if [ -e /etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-screen ]; then
                    PROMPT_COMMAND=/etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-screen
            else
        PROMPT_COMMAND='printf "\033]0;%s@%s:%s\033\\" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/~}"'
            fi
            ;;
    *)
            [ -e /etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-default ] && PROMPT_COMMAND=/etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-default
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: Copying my .bashrc file from a working server to the oddball server fixed it. I'll go back and review why they were different in the first place later. Thanks!